# SVN hook / svn up / conflict

Tags: svn

When I do a Svn up in a file with a local modification that can produce a conflict.

Is it possible to cancel svn update with a hook and write a message?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this, why not just catch the conflict when it happens?

Comment: @kaerast I worked at a place where the boss liked to edit in the working copy that we used as the production document root.  Having conflicts in that would be embarrassing!

See http://blog.joopp.com/2008/12/15/flickr-version-control/

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to ignore any changes that would cause a particular file to be conflicted, then you probably want `svn update --accept=mine-full`.  This means that if a change would cause a conflict, discard the incoming changes.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

If you want to decide whether a change to any file would cause a conflict, use `svn status -u` to determine what changes you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to do it server side.

However, as of version 1.5, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/tsvn_1.5_releasenotes.html) supports client-side hooks, including pre-update and post-update.  I'm not sure if any other clients do.

That, in combination with

```
  svn status --show-updates --verbose
```

and some scripting, may let you do what you want.

According to the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch03s05.html), svn status --show-updates --verbose will give you a status list like this example:

```
  $ svn status --show-updates --verbose
  M      *        44        23    sally     README
  M               44        20    harry     bar.c
         *        44        35    harry     stuff/trout.c
  D               44        19    ira       stuff/fish.c
  A                0         ?     ?        stuff/things/bloo.h
  Status against revision:   46
```

If I understand this correctly, any time you see M (for Modified locally) and * (changed in the repository) for the same file, you're going to have a conflict.

So all you should need to do is parse that output and abort the update if it looks like you'll have a conflict.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You will want a pre-commit hook, in your svn repository directory there is a hooks directory, containing something like pre-commit.bat (on windows, or pre-commit.sh).  SVN will execute this before you commit, so just replace this with a script you wish to run and you will be able to halt the commit to SVN.

Comment: Is this question for you, or for your users?

Comment: it an anwser to this anwser, i delete it.
I want a "pre-update" or "post-update" because i work with SVN in production, if a file is in conflit it will be corrupt and will not work. So i must cancel the update and don't corrupt file.

Comment: I mean, are you a sysadmin trying to solve this problem for your users, or are you one of a number of developers working with subversion?

Comment: developer, but i sysadmin for Subversion server.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do exactly what you want to do. The file in subversion should never be corrupted by what is checked in by someone else.

Comment: Most dev processes work by before a developer commits a file to subversion, they should first do an SVN status (and modern IDEs should automatically do this for them anyway), this will tell them if their version is out of date. The subversion update will then attempt to merge the differences (a good visual tool like tortoise should do the trick here) on the developers _local_ copy, it is then up to the developer to ensure the merge has not introduced any bugs before they commit the changes. Alternatively, developers should lock the files they are working with.
(P.S. I'm a developer!)

Comment: i know, but it's on command line with php file. if someone make a local modification, and make a svn update after, a merge or a conflict will be done, you are agree ? if it's a conflict the file will contain "<<<Mine" tag, that is not a good Php syntax. so the file is corrupted (not for SVN but for Php). That's why i look for a solution to don't update a file if a conflict happend. Do you think a security exist to don't make a conflict on a file if a conflict is detected ?

Comment: Their merge will happen on their local file, if they choose to check it in and break the build, they should pay the usual price for doing this - public shaming, i.e. buying the donuts/coffee/villa in France for the team.  Not sure if there are any continuous integration tools for php, but either way, a developer should take responsibility for what they check-in and they should understand the tools they use and their implications.

There might be a way of setting up a client tool to not update if there is a conflict, but I don't think it can be done on the SVN server.

Comment: You are right, but developer can do mistake, and it's not the first to make the same mistake;) i will seach if client can do that, thanks.

Comment: Fair enough, let us know if you find anything!

Comment: The question isn't about commits.  The question is, if doing an `svn update` would cause a conflict with local modifications, can the commit be aborted before any files are changed at all.